# ASP.NET component to edit .resx files

Tags: asp.net, localization, translation, resx

I'm developing a multilingual web site and the localization is done mostly by using .resx files. But now I need to enable users with some permissions to edit resource files online from the web site.
Does anyone know of any existing component to help achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best thing you can do is move to a DB driven approach.

**Rick Strahl** has this excellent article: [Creating a Data Driven ASP.NET Localization
Resource Provider and Editor](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/) with **free source code**!

It even has a **Import** feature so you don't have to re-translate the work done so far.

**Edit:** if you insist on editing the XML files, this article may help: [Updatable ASP.NET ResX Resource Provider – yes, it’s possible!](http://www.onpreinit.com/2009/06/updatable-aspnet-resx-resource-provider.html)

Comment: Those look like great solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider this step once again. First of all resx files are compiled instead of used directly so any changes require page recompilation*. The other thing is that it might be a serious security threat - you allow users to modify files in your application folder.

*- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: So I'm guessing there's no "clean" way of accessing the .resx files other than to just open them "old-school" style, messing around with the XML, and writing them to the file system again. And then the app will figure out they have been changed and compile them at runtime.
About the security risk, the .resx files only hold translation strings, and the users changing them would need the appropriate permissions. That left me wondering, could some "injection attack" be made by inserting some code into a .resx file?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this [Resource Blender](http://www.resourceblender.com/) application that's similar to what I was looking for:

> ResourceBlender is an open-source
> translation and internationalization
> application which offers an easy way
> to manage localized resources for
> inclusion with different applications.
> Available as an ASP.NET web
> application and a WPF desktop
> application, it makes localizing
> applications a breeze. ResourceBlender
> generates localized resources in
> different formats from a central
> database for inclusion with different
> applications.
>
> Key features offered include:
>
> - Export resources to .NET .resx files, Java .properties, GNU .po / gettext, XHTML entities and more.
> - Import/Export translation data as XML spreadsheets to make editing more convenient.
> - Use one translations database to keep localizations in-sync.
> - Supports MySQL, SQL Server and SQLite, so no external database is required.
> - Migrate from existing .resx or .properties files with an import wizard.
> - Easy for both translators and project owners/admins.
> - Free and open source.
> - Automatic machine translation with Google Translate.
> - Custom templates for resource formats.