# Editing .resx files on a deployed Application through code not manually

Tags: asp.net, resx

I have a few applications deployed which would benefit the ability to edit the text in the the .resx files from forms within the application.

Things like welcome messages could then be customised by the clients of these applications.

One way to do this would be through a database but this would stump my the multilingual ability of the resx files.

Is there a way to edit this through code or can resx files only be edited through editing the file manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar discussion can be found here:

[ASP.NET component to edit .resx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789588/asp-net-component-to-edit-resx-files)